# Verify if two strings are equal in C++

Tags: c++, string, function, boolean

I'm doing an assignment that requires me to use a function to check whether two strings are equal. I keep getting a parse error on line 20, where the function is called, and I don't know what's wrong. Please take a look and let me know if you see what could be causing the problem. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool checker(string firstWordParameter, string secondWordParameter);

int main()
{
    string firstWord, secondWord;
    bool match;

    cout << "Hello user.\n"
         << "This program will determine whether two words are the same.\n"
         << "Please enter your first word you would like to check: ";
    getline(cin, firstWord);
    cout << "Great, now enter the second word: ";
    getline(cin, secondWord);

    match = bool checker(firstWord, secondWord);

    if(match == true){
        cout << "Match.";
    }else{
        cout << "Totally not a match.";
    }

    return 0; 
}

bool checker(string firstWordParameter, string secondWordParameter)
{
    if(firstWordParameter == secondWordParameter){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It'd be nice if you could tell us where line 20 is...

Comment: why didn't you just look at line 20 for a few minutes? Or at least just post the surrounding (+- 1 line) code? :p

Answer (score 7):

Try changing

```
match = bool checker(firstWord, secondWord);
```

into

```
match = checker(firstWord, secondWord);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, that's all I needed. Works now :)

Answer (score 5):

Line 20 is

```
 match = bool checker(firstWord, secondWord);
```

Change it to

```
match = checker(firstWord, secondWord);
```

Also when you see error in compiler, double click it then it will show you the line with the error.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I knew it was line 20, I just didn't understand why it wasn't liking my function call. I appreciate the help, this site's user's can be vicious.

Comment: Thanks, Will appreciate if you accept my answer (Tick it)